# Mongoose async queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I have a site on nodejs-express and when user increment his balance:

```
User.update({steamid: user.steamid}, {$set: {wallet: user.wallet + 1)}}, function(err){
  if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

But when user increment his "wallet" at least twice in a row mongoose add only 1 point in "wallet". What I should do? Maybe add queue array and then call their with async?

Comment: What you should do is use the atomic `$inc` operator instead. [MongoDB Documentation on `$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should Increment instead of set.

```
User.update({steamid: user.steamid}, {$inc:{wallet:1}}, function(err){
    if(err)console.log(err)
});
```

I generally use this when I don't need information about the model quantity and only need the difference value that will operate on the model itself.

Comment: Anytime, friend. @SaidGadjiev